# Selecting SAP grey box element in a list

Tags: rpa, sap-gui, blueprism

I'm wondering if you guys have an idea on how to handle this problem.

**Process:**

First I iterate trough this collection. If the input value is the same as the item of the grid box it will stop and select this item.

[image: View of SAP GridBox]

Note that every spy mode will select EVERYTHING and the only way to actually read this is with SAP GridBox.

The problem here is that I need to click the small grey square on the left of the selected Notification. I cannot select it with any hotkey or with a spy mode.

[image: Small grey square MANUALLY selected]

My idea was to use capture an highlighted item with the Region mode and then move 5px to the left. But this does not seem to work...

Any suggestion are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly the shortcut for selecting an entire row in Sap Grid is `Shift + Space`. You need to have a cell selected first, though.